Clone a repository's dist folder, to another repository that is hosted on github pages
I have a personal portfolio that is hosted on github pages, something like myname.github.io (so it's a static website)
Recently I've created anoter repo, that uses webpack, so the actual website needs to be built, inside a 'dist' folder
I want to clone the second repo (or just the dist folder) in the repo with personal portfolio
I made the clone with git submodule, then I ran "npm run build" so that the dist folder was created, and made a commit & push to main branch. Normally, I would expect to be able to access myname.github.io/submodule/dist/index.html but it returns a 404.
I don't want to deploy the dist folder of second repository, but clone it as "static" inside personal portfolio, and serve it from there
